# object leaves dark parts after animating diffuse to transparent material

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

i have an object that starts out with a diffuse shader and then changes to transparent(I animated the mix shader to do it). However when it goes transparent theres dark bits leftover like theyre from a shadow or sumn. The object has multiple materials so i had to animate the shader change on multiple materials. I think this might have had something to do with it.
on the left you of the pciture you can see the postbox as it fades out has some dark parts as it disappers. they stay there after it goes fully transparent too.
using cycles in blender 2.79 btw[image]